# MAGMA: One-sided ideals in finitely presented algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma-cas

So I have the following code in MAGMA to obtain a right ideal in the free algebra:

```
K := RationalField();
F<x> := FreeAlgebra(K,1);
I := rideal<F|x^2>;
```

I would like to be able to do the same for a finitely-presented algebra, for example:

```
K := RationalField();
F<x> := FreeAlgebra(K,1);
A<x> := quo<F|x^3>;

I := rideal<A|x^2>;
```

However, I get the following error `Runtime error in ideal< ... >: Rhs argument 1 is invalid for this constructor`. Does anyone know a method to do this?

Comment: I'm just trying using the calculator provided online to see if it's useful

Comment: To people: Please don't downvote MAGMA questions that are well-written, simply because they are about "programming". This is mathematical software, just like MATLAB, and there does not exist a forum for MAGMA software outside of math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
K := RationalField();
F<x> := FreeAlgebra(K,1);
A := quo<F|x^3>;
I := ideal<A|x^2>;
```

MAGMA sometimes gives problems if you redefine the x.  Also, since your algebra is commutative, the rideal and lideal constructors are not available.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the algebra I'm actually working with is the second Weyl algebra but I didn't want to write down all the relations here! I'll try this without redefining my variables and see whether it'll accept rideal constructors.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that I tried the rideal constructor with an algebra that is definitely noncommutative ($A_2$) and got the same error.

Comment: Here's my code: 


`K:=RationalField();
F<y1,x1,y0,x0>:=FreeAlgebra(K,4);
A:=quo<F|x0*y0-y0*x0-1,x1*y1-y1*x1-1, x0*x1-x1*x0, x0*y1-y1*x0, y0*x1-x1*y0, y0*y1-y1*y0>;
I:=rideal<A|x0*y0, x1*y1>;`